# Is it possible to communicate with browser's to disable "inspect element"

Tags: internet-explorer, google-chrome, browser

Is it possible to communicate with browser's to disable "inspect element" on internet explorer, google chrome, etc?

Comment: No, why would browsers allow you to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The least I can think of is disabling right-click, but you can't prevent the user from opening it manually on their browser. (<kbd>CTRL-Shift-I</kbd>Windows, <kbd>CMND-Shift-I</kbd>Mac on Chrome.